# C# ASP.NET MVC can not pass 2 objects in TempData from one controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have code in a C# application that uses JSON.SerializeObject to store data in TempData in one controller and then I use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in a second controller.  This is the code in the first controller:

```
TempData["participantData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(participantData);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MainPage");
```

In the above code, I serialize an object called participantData.  participantData is defined like this:

```
ParticipantLoadData participantData = new ParticipantLoadData();
```

The ParticipantLoadData class looks like this:

```
    public class CurrentParticipant
{
    public string comp_first_day_of_year { get; set; }
    public string comp_rate_of_return { get; set; }

    public string ss_LastName { get; set; }
    public string ss_FirstName { get; set; }
    public string ss_SocSec { get; set; }
    public string ss_Bal { get; set; }
    public string ss_Pending { get; set; }
    public string ss_LoanOB { get; set; }
    public string ss_VstBal { get; set; }
    public string ss_ValDate { get; set; }
    public int ss_LoanFund { get; set; }

    public string fld_CY_IEXP { get; set; }
    public string fld_Salary { get; set; }

    public string th_last_contribution { get; set; }
    public string th_last_contribution_date { get; set; }

}
```

This all works fine as I am able to retrieve TempData["participantData"] from within the MainPage controller.

When I try to send a second object to TempData, I end up generating a "This site can't be reached" error.  This is what I added:

I tried to add a second object to the TempData.  I created a List where the Fund Class looks like this:

```
public class Fund
{
    public int FundNumber { get; set; }
    public string FundName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I populated a list of type Fund with this code:

```
List<Fund> FundList = new List<Fund>();

var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath + "/txt";
var FILENAME = System.IO.Path.Combine(webRoot, "fund_list.txt");
{
    foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(FILENAME))
    {
        var oneFund = new Fund();
        oneFund.FundNumber = int.Parse(line.Substring(1, 4));
        if (oneFund.FundNumber > 0)
        {
            oneFund.FundName = FundNameException(line.Substring(6, line.Length - 6));
            FundList.Add(oneFund);
        }
   }
}
```

This code loads 2000 elements into the FundList.

When this loop completes, I execute these lines of code:

```
TempData["FundList"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FundList, Formatting.Indented);
TempData["participantData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(participantData);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MainPage");
```

I have a break point set at the return, which I hit.  When I look at the TempData["FundList"], it appears to contain the correct data in the correct format.  I also have a break point set in controller MainPage on the first line of code within the ActionResult Index() which never gets hit.

Any idea why adding this second object to TempData would be causing an issue?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a model that contains the objects that you want to pass.

Comment: Adding multiple key-value pairs to TempData is fine. The error "This site can't be reached" is from something else and not the number of TempData keys assigned.

Comment: TempData is itself stored as Session data, so it is unlikely that a data quota/limit is exceeded. In any case, this can be checked by only storing one or two funds items read from disk and seeing if the same issue persists. (That said, it’s good to keep the session size “in check”.)

Comment: Also, TempData uses internal serialization (backed via Session serialization) so there is not normally a need to use to/from JSON methods to add values to TempData.